ValueError: 'tab10' is not a valid color value and code optimization
Im trying to predict MNIST data  using my own k-means algorithm.
What I want to do:
1. MNIST data is loaded and pixel values are normalized to the range [0, 1].
2. Parameters for the K-means algorithm are set: the number of clusters (k), initial centroids (Z0), and the maximum number of iterations (NITERMAX).
3. The K-means algorithm is executed on the MNIST data to classify images into k clusters.
4. A figure with subplots is created, where each subplot represents an image from the dataset.
5. For each image, the image itself is displayed, and the subplot title is set with the label predicted by K-means for that image.
6. The figure with all images and their predicted labels is shown.
Problems:
1. Error: ValueError: 'tab10' is not a valid color value.
2. The algorithm takes approximately 2 hours to finish running on my Jupyter.
3. Since I have an error, I don't know if the algorithm contains the logic described above
def k_means_fit(X: np.array, Z0: np.array, NITERMAX: int) -> tuple:
    Z = np.array(Z0)
    centroids_history = [Z.copy()]
    inertia_history = [] 

    for _ in range(NITERMAX):
        distances = np.linalg.norm(X.values - Z[:, np.newaxis, :], axis=2)
        labels = np.argmin(distances, axis=0)
        Z_new = np.array([X.values[labels == k].mean(axis=0) for k in range(len(Z))])
        inertia = np.sum(np.min(distances, axis=0))
        inertia_history.append(inertia)
        if np.allclose(Z, Z_new):
            print("Converged at iteration", _)
            break
        Z = Z_new
        centroids_history.append(Z.copy())

    inertia_diff = [inertia_history[i] - inertia_history[i-1] for i in range(1, len(inertia_history))]

    return Z, labels, centroids_history, inertia_history, inertia_diff

from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

# Load MNIST data
mnist = fetch_openml('mnist_784', version=1)
X = mnist.data / 255.0  # Normalize pixel values to [0, 1]
X_df = pd.DataFrame(X)

# K-means parameters
k = 20  # Number of clusters
Z0 = X_df.sample(k).values  # Initial centroids randomly sampled from data
NITERMAX = 100  # Maximum iterations

# Run K-means
final_centroids, labels, _, _, _ = k_means_fit(X_df, Z0, NITERMAX)

# Visualize classification for all images
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=X.shape[0], ncols=1, figsize=(15, 10))  # One subplot per image
cmap = ListedColormap('tab10')  # Colormap for visualization

for i in range(X.shape[0]):
  # Show image
    axs[i].imshow(X.iloc[i].values.reshape(28, 28), cmap=cmap)
  # Set title with predicted label
    axs[i].set_title(f'Prediction: {labels[i]}')
  # Turn off axes
    axs[i].axis('off')

plt.suptitle('K-means Classification for All Images')
plt.tight_layout()  # Adjust spacing between subplots
plt.show()

Plot example:


"Error: ValueError: 'tab10' is not a valid color value." Separate this out into a toy example and troubleshoot it. If you can't trouble shoot it at that point, then you'd post about it. Then you could post about 2 and 3, separately. (Maybe? I worry about the suitability.) Please consult How do I ask a good question? and how it stresses 'On-topic'. Yours seems to fall under debugging as written and doesn't contain the minimal code to produce the error about 'tab10'. In the first part of my comment, I suggested an option to address that.

Replace cmap = ListedColormap('tab10') by cmap ='tab10'
